# Return of Html page in springboot controller

Tags: java, html, spring-boot

> I created a login page inside template directory when I return that
> page in controller it gives me whiteable error page 404.
> this is my login file directory
> [image]

.

> LoginController.java

```
@Controller
@RequestMapping("/api/nilmani/v1/login")
public class LoginController {
    
    @GetMapping("/LoginHome")
    public String getPage() {
        return "/templates/Login.html";
    }

}
```

Comment: Did you try to write the whole SRC of the HTML file? So also the folders that are before */templates/Login.html*